# Is there a way to prevent astsa::sarima() from plotting?

Tags: r

I want to run many models like this:

```
myModel = astsa::sarima(xdata = iris[,1], p = 1, d = 0, q = 0, xreg = iris[, 2:4], details = FALSE)
```

I would absolutely want to avoid the plots, because they slow everything down. Is there a way? I did not find something in the documentation

For the record, I am using R 3.2.2 and astsa V1.6.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: interesting, does not seem to support `options`. I looked in the actual package, the package's code is in `R` folder but it is int `.rdb` and `.rdx` files. At worst you can look up how to edit those and turn the ploting off.

Comment: You can edit the function and remove the part where plotting starts.

Comment: You could change the source code. If you feel adventurous, fork [the package](https://github.com/cran/astsa), make adjustments and install it locally as a new version which has plotting turned off or better yet, has an option which supports turning plotting off.

Comment: I actually created a sarimaCustom() function, copying the source code and disabling the plots. However, I do not feel very good about it. Maybe this is something the user should have control of...

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm a little late but if you set the parameter Model = FALSE, no plot will be made.

E.g.

```
myModel = astsa::sarima(xdata = iris[,1], p = 1, d = 0, q = 0, xreg = 
iris[, 2:4], details = FALSE, Model = FALSE)
```

Comment: For me it is only details=FALSE that remove plots and print.